# Equality not working while comparing Integer and int

Tags: java

```
Integer startNode;
int walker
..... // some logic

if(startNode != Integer.valueOf(walker)) {
   //do something
}
```

This if block is executing even if startNode and walker have same value (in my case 151) 
[image]